# I can ping my gateway but can't ping yahoo, microsoft and bing

Tags: networking

I can ping my gateway but can't ping yahoo.com, microsoft.com or google.com. How can I fix this problem?

```
ping microsoft.com
PING microsoft.com (23.100.122.175) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- microsoft.com ping statistics ---
20 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 19151ms
```

And:

```
ping google.com
PING google.com(yk-in-x64.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4002:c07::64)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7999ms
```

---

My `resolv.conf`:

[image]

Comment: What type of device is your gateway?  Can you issue `route` on it and your local machine and then add it to your question?

Comment: yes it is on my local machine. I have window10 and that work fine on all pings. but when I use both Ubuntu and Kali Linux I can't ping like what I said in above to my question.

Comment: Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         homeportal      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0

Comment: TTL too short for the round trip?  Just guessing here.  Or perhaps the gateway is eating your UDP packets...

Comment: I would recommend installing `traceroute` then running a `traceroute www.google.com` or similar to see where the connection is dying.  Need to eliminate your computer as being the problem.

Comment: I still having no luck :(

Comment: @jdthood can you help me ?

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](https://superuser.com/questions/1176469/i-can-ping-my-gateway-but-cant-ping-yahoo-microsoft-and-bing). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: still no solution yet to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Edit your /etc/resolv.conf and put `nameserver 8.8.8.8` as the un-commented first line.

You can make this change permanent by editing your `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and putting `nameserver 8.8.8.8` as the first un-commented line there.

Some sites such as **microsoft.com** blocks the ping packets.  However, the ones such as **google.com** and **yahoo.com** will respond.

**Update:**

Run these commands:

```
$ sudo apt install traceroute
$ sudo traceroute 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: question is there a name server for Microsoft? what other name servers should I add ? What other files should I configure to make my network work correctly ?

Comment: The problem that you're having has to do with the name server that you are using.  Microsoft as well as any other site has their name servers.  But they may not configured to provide name service to computers outside of their own network.  Google, on the other hand, does provide a free public name server (8.8.8.8).  The resolution is for you to either configure your own, use one provided by your IT (which windows is most likely doing), or add a primary name server to your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.  The latter is most likely the most common and easiest route.

Comment: thank you for that answer anything more that I have to tweak on other parts of the network configure files or that it ?

Comment: @jamesMarsh No.  That's it.  You can now verify that you have a working DNS entry "8.8.8.8" as provided by Googe by referencing your resolv.conf file with: `ls /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: well I edit my main post. But it still not let me ping Google.com. I added a picture also how I add the name server to the file.

Comment: any other clues that you can see what I did wrong in editing the config file ?

Comment: @jamesMarsh The image you show does not have this as the first first line.  It needs to be `nameserver 8.8.8.8` for the first line.  You have `nameserver 192.168.1.254` as the first line.  Remove the other items you have and just leave `nameserver 8.8.8.8` as the only un-commented line.  When you want to show the content of your files, use the copy and paste feature of text, not a picture.  I wanted to copy the content from what you have and paste the problem in this comment, but you can't copy text from a picture.  The text in the questions is much easier to deal with than the pictures.

Comment: @jamesMarsh Will you run the two commands in the update section of the answer.  Then copy and paste the text to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53018/discussion-between-james-marsh-and-l-d-james).

Comment: I am back into the chatroom waiting for you .

Comment: @ L. D. James  I am going into chat room

Comment: still no solution yet to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could give the symptom you describe is loss of DNS service.  Check the DNS settings you're using to be sure they're valid (your Internet provider should have documented their DNS IP addresses, or you can use the Google DNS at 8:8:8:8 and 8:8:4:4).

Comment: NDS works, domain is resolving.

Comment: I can ping that numbers but when I ping .
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 34.602/34.862/35.135/0.195 ms
ping yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com
--- yahoo.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3999ms

Comment: Yahoo may block ping requests, but as far as I know, Google does not.  And, as noted in comment above, if your're not getting a DNS error or "server not found" type failure, your DNS lookups are working.  Just on a hunch, try a `traceroute` (might be `tracert`, been a while since I typed that command) to the same domain.  If you get out a ways and then it stops, that'll tell you something.

Comment: I still not solved my problem.